# Disable kendo ui tooltip per series

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to have a pie chart that will have disable tooltip and another that will have a tooltip enabled. I have tried to enable the tooltip per series but it didn't work.

```
{
  category: "Asia",
  value: 53.8,
  color: "#9de219",
  tooltip: {
    visible: true
  }
}
```

Here is the dojo
http://dojo.telerik.com/OKOLE

Answer (score 0):

I have made it through series hover event.

```
seriesHover: e => {
    if(e.category == 'disabledCategory') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
 }
```